# Typescript - Dynamic types

Tags: typescript, typeerror, typescript-generics

I am trying to type this example => [typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBCBGArGBeGBvAUDHMBmArmMAIwBcMAFOjAIYwC+FNtF0ATgJZgDmjAlKgB8GGKEggANgFMAdJJA9KtQQwA02XIWIAmCtRjxGzQxTAEAtvGnsBw0eIhS5CpfFUaGmTNuBRO4DDSAB7SwABiRH4BYAA8ANLSAJ5BwVDSYAAmEDAA1skgeDBQSQAO0oVwSEKU+UkUiUlqMKW07LQWEBQACm0d0unsELEl5ZUIiADajQC6QpMADDOCWLhi4ND4URSjFUUT08kzqFVTdTPea+wDBOxgW8SUre2d-N5emCFhkcT+4JQAcl8JABzRYFABtABAk+oQiUT+YEBvh0oNE8AoJAEQA)

```
const obj = {
    func1: ({ a }: { a: string }) => { console.log(a) },
    func2: ({ b }: { b: number }) => { console.log(b) },
}

function execFunction<Key extends keyof typeof obj>(key: Key, params: Parameters<typeof obj[Key]>[0]) {
    const func: typeof obj[Key] = obj[key]

    return func(params)

}

execFunction('func1', { a: 'a' })
execFunction('func2', { b: 1 })
```

When i use execFunction auto-completion work fine but i have an error on `func(params)` but i don't know why. Any ideas?

```
Argument of type '{ a: string; } | { b: number; }' is not assignable to parameter of type '{ a: string; } & { b: number; }'.
  Type '{ a: string; }' is not assignable to type '{ a: string; } & { b: number; }'.
    Property 'b' is missing in type '{ a: string; }' but required in type '{ b: number; }'.(2345)
input.tsx(3, 22): 'b' is declared here.
```

I try to infer types but i don't find work around...

Thanks for help

Comment: It's just TypeScript being dumb about actual types inside a generic function. Use a type assertion to silence it.

Comment: TS can't perform the sort of higher-order reasoning needed to see this as safe.  You can assert or refactor your types as described in [ms/TS#47109](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/47109) and as shown [in this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/wOrddW).  If you're interested in such refactoring and it meets your needs I could write up an answer explaining; otherwise, what am I missing?

Comment: Thanks for your reply ! @jcalz I am interested in your explanations it meets my needs.

Answer (score 1):

TypeScript isn't able to look at `obj` and "see" that the generic operation `obj[key]` (where `key` is of [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) type `Key`) will be a function that accepts `Parameters<typeof obj[Key]>[0]` as an argument.  The name of [the `Parameters` utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#parameterstype) is suggestive to humans, but it means nothing to the compiler, and the actual type it has to analyze is a generic [conditional type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html), and these are basically opaque to the compiler.  It mostly just gives up and treats it as an unknown type.  Once the compiler gives up this way, it proceeds by just widening `Key` to its [constraint](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints) `"func1" | "func2"`, and you get that `obj[key]` is a [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) of functions, that `params` is a union of arguments, and the compiler is worried about the possibility that `params`'s type will be the union member not corresponding to that of `obj[key]`.  This is actually technically possible:

```
execFunction(Math.random() < 0.5 ? "func1" : "func2", { a: "" }); // no error!
```

But it's presumably unlikely and similar constructs are often allowed in the language.  Anyway, the only way the compiler would let you call `func(params)` in the case where `func` is a union is when `params` is an [*intersection*](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#intersection-types) of the allowable params to the function (see [the TS3.3 release notes](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-3.html#improved-behavior-for-calling-union-types) for more information).  That would definitely be safe (e.g., `{a: "", b: 123}` would work for both `func1` and `func2`).  And that's why you're getting the error.  But it's not what you're trying to do.

This issue of trying to call a union of functions with a union of parameters in situations where it is definitely safe (or technically unsafe but unlikely to be a problem in practice) is the subject of [microsoft/TypeScript#30581](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30581).  TypeScript doesn't directly support "correlated unions"; there's no easy way to tell the compiler that the *pair* of `func` and `params` go together, if both are of union types.

---

Anyway, here's something the compiler *does* understand:

```
interface Arg {
    func1: { a: string };
    func2: { b: number };
}

const obj: { [K in keyof Arg]: (arg: Arg[K]) => void } = {
    func1: ({ a }) => { console.log(a.toUpperCase()) },
    func2: ({ b }) => { console.log(b.toFixed(1)) }
}

function execFunction<K extends keyof Arg>(key: K, params: Arg[K]) {
    const func = obj[key];
    return func(params); 
}
```

In this case the type of `obj` is a [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html), so when you [index into](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html) it with a generic key, the compiler sees the resulting type as a single generic function type of the form `(arg: Arg[K]) => void`.  And since `params` is of type `Arg[K]`, that call is allowed.  No unions-of-functions are involved.

This general approach is the recommended way to deal with correlated unions, and it's presented in detail in [microsoft/TypeScript#47109](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/47109).  The idea is to take a basic key-value type like `Args`, and represent all interactions as generic indexing into that type, or into mapped types over that type.

Note that the actual types are equivalent in your non-working version and in the above working version.  But since the compiler cannot verify this equivalence, such refactoring is necessary.

---

So your original code doesn't work as written, and the above refactoring does.   In the interest of the minimal change necessary to get your version working, one could do this:

```
function execFunction<K extends keyof typeof obj>(
  key: K, 
  params: Parameters<typeof obj[K]>[0]
) {
    const func: { [P in keyof typeof obj]:
        (arg: Parameters<typeof obj[P]>[0]) => void }[K] = obj[key]
    return func(params); // okay
}
```

This ends up performing a similar type refactoring: we are asking the compiler to verify that `obj` is of type `{ [P in keyof typeof obj]: (arg: Parameters<typeof obj[P]>[0]) => void }`, a mapped type over `typeof obj`, and that indexing into this with `k` of generic type `K` produces a single function `func` of generic type `(arg: Parameters<typeof obj[K]>[0]) => void`.  Once we have that we can call `func(params)` because `params` is explicitly of type `Parameters<typeof obj[K]>[0]`.  The compiler doesn't understand what `Parameters<typeof obj[K]>[0]` is any more than it did before; it's still opaque and similar to `func: (arg: Blargh) => void` and `params: Blargh`.  But since those are identical types the compiler allows the call.

It's up to you which refactoring you'd want to use, if any (you could just decide to move ahead and use a [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) instead of refactoring).  Personally I think the one with `Args` is easier for a human being to follow and therefore might be easier to maintain.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/HYQwtgpgzgDiDGEAEAhEUCW8BqEBOmA9sEgN4BQSVSGwALvgGYLICCeA5mZdb4wK7B4ARgBcZJCHFQ6eWlwC+Abh68qAoQCZxpJACNxwfmD34ky1efKX4xGUkJ6AVjqQBtANI0SAawgBPQkYkdg4AXXEAChBOcVDPMIBKJABeAD4kADdCDAATc1TuNWoNESjdEHNk9IlbYChCABsIADpGwg5olrpCAFUYGHwAYXQISMTkhQAaSz5BeG0kSN09KtSM3TqG5raOyL1uwgAxDAAPCFzI4QmrXgVrOaE6DGIkCHP4I-nn4gAeL3eDGAuSgSD8gWCoTSkXB4g8UyQcDw4CgcU4CWSFGKVC2dCQpUKjicbnBYRU2KQeAgdH4eBIpUiSJRiXJ1HuvHeEE+3xewEiAFkQHQABYtZHAwhgcZIX5IAAMLQArEgAPxIABEpWE6qQ4k18006oRFT1OoULKQAHpLUhAHwbgHZdwCwBIAhMkA8H-ke7kUCQWAsJD82gYMAgRpDYUgYAcZAUGx2PFEwpY7Fa8qScyuKRIGRySNrGqbOxNVrtTogSYzCmlRbLfTpiQGJBGExmc3rWqFnYl-blyyex7wH4kTncp68-5vU5AkFggJBJB0fyDOdE6GwpDwxExFHiAAKW8gDAIvwXS+CRISaTccqSRWxuPx81cbh33hnEPni4gy+cEVm2OisRIHuyIHvgUDHp+37EjuYSXte1QZNkeTmAkhLOCSARhH+VBUjSdIPkIjL7lAFrWg4PggP4vaWMOXyjsQkQAORaoxxqSOIjEgIxVQ0R8dEDryTFVqx9biMIPEekAA)